# How do I take value from array of objects?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, remix, arrays

I have a problem with my code.

```
contract Registration {
address public owner;
uint conceptPrice;
uint conceptValue;

function Registration(uint _conceptPrice) public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    conceptPrice = _conceptPrice;
    conceptValue = conceptPrice;
}
/////////////////////////////////////
/* Others code*/
/////////////////////////////////////
struct Request {
    uint reqId;
    uint amount;
    uint percentage;
    address modAdd;
    //0 for pending, 1 accept, 2 decline
    uint state;
}
//
Request[] public requests;
//mapping (uint => Request) requests;
function request(uint _amount, uint _percentage) public returns (uint numRequests) {
    bool present = false;
    for (uint i = 0; i <= participants.length; i++) {
        if (participants[i] == msg.sender) {
            present = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    //
    if (msg.sender == owner || _amount < conceptPrice || _amount < balances[msg.sender] || _percentage > 5 || present == false) return;
    Request memory req = Request({reqId : requests.length + 1, amount : _amount, percentage : _percentage, modAdd : msg.sender, state : 0});
    //bissogna togliere i soldi a chi fa l'offerta
    requests.push(req);
    numRequests = requests.length;
}

uint[] ident;
uint[] per;
uint[] amountV;

function pendingRequest() public {

    for (uint i = 0; i == requests.length; i++) {
        if (requests[i].state == 0) {
            ident.push(requests[i].reqId);
            per.push(requests[i].percentage);
            amountV.push(requests[i].amount);
        }
    }
}
function printReq() public constant returns (uint[] ident_){
    ident_ = ident;
}
}
```

I created two different request (numRequests =2) but when i try to take value from array of object Request through the function pendingRequest i have an error:
status  0x0 Transaction mined but execution failed.
Array requests have values inside for example requests at position one is:[requests[1]](https://postimg.cc/B8LxLPmn)
Why?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error with your [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp):

```
for (uint i = 0; i == requests.length; i++) { ...  <-- this code is wrong
```

You probably are trying to iterate over the values of `requests`, so your code should look like:

```
function pendingRequest() public {
    for (uint i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
        ... do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: No, i have same problem with "=="

Comment: `==` is not correct. You need to check if `i` is less than `requests.length` (`<`). That first code block was me just copying the incorrect part of your code.

Comment: There are numerous other errors with your code though (as it is written in your post), it will certainly not work even if you fix this one issue. I think you need to take a step back and iterate on smaller pieces, getting each one to work on its own.

Comment: What do you mean? If variable requests is public i can know output and it has value inside. For example: [link](https://postimg.cc/B8LxLPmn)

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure what you are asking me. The output you are getting looks right to me for an index of `requests`

Comment: My problem is when use a cycle to take values from array requests the index i doesn't point to right location. For example the array ident is empty outside the function pendingRequest

Comment: How are you checking the value of `ident`?

Comment: Sorry, i added function printReq to my code. There ident retuns empty array

Comment: You [shouldn't be returning the whole array](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html#members) like that, instead write a getter function which returns a single index.